# Generalised directions

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space, $A$ a real vectorspace. Let a map $\phi:X \setminus \{0\} \to A$ such that it satisfies the following properties

- $\phi(\lambda x) = \phi(x)$ for every $\lambda >0$
- if $\|x\|=\|y\|$, then $\phi(x+y) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \phi(x)+\phi(y) \right)$

be called a direction.

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean norm, there is a natural direction given by $(x,y) \mapsto \tan^{-1}(y/x)$, i.e. the 'angle map'. I have the following questions.

- Are there directions on $\mathbb{R}^n$?
- Which normed spaces admit directions?

NB. I am not completely sure about the well-posedness of this question, I was trying to make the statement general, but still understandable. If you have suggestions or questions, I am more than open.

For this reason I also provide some motivation. I am working on a problem, where I am taking the average directions of vectors repeatedly. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, I have an easy job, since this is equal to taking the average of angles, and I can use this to reduce the problem to something I can solve.
I would like to do the same in $\mathbb{R}^n$: Instead of dealing with vectors, find a way to only deal with 'their angles', which should obey some simple rules, when considering the 'angle' of the sum of some other 'angles'.

Comment: Your "natural direction" on $R^2$ is not well defined.